# Google Earth Capture KML of current globe view

Tags: javascript, kml, google-earth

Does anyone know anyway to use something similar to polygon.getKml() except for the current LookAt or Camera containing all of the elements inside of the Earth View?

I have tried something along the lines of ge.getView().getKml() but getKml can only be applied to certain objects.

Also you can get each of the elements KML individually using a loop and:

```
ge.getFeatures().getChildNodes().item(#).getKml();
```

however this will not give you the lookat or the camera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either

```
var lookAt = ge.getView().copyAsLookAt(ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND);
```

or

```
var camera = ge.getView().copyAsCamera(ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND);
```

see this page for documentation
https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/camera_control